# set result value on JSON Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I have a `var data` with a result array JSON value like this:

```
[
   {"vehicle_id":"1", "model_name":"sedan"},
   {"vehicle_id":"2", "model_name":"elf"},
   {"vehicle_id":"3", "model_name":"truck"}
]
```

I want to set each value on new variable like this :

```
var newdata = [
    {
        text: Obj.model_name
        value: Obj.vehicle_id
    },
    {
        text: Obj.model_name
        value: Obj.vehicle_id
    },
    ......
];
```

How to set each value on the variable above ?

I already try this approach :

```
var newdata = [
    $.each(data, function(index, Obj){
       {
           text: Obj.model_name
           value: Obj.vehicle_id
       }
    })
];
```

But seems it's not working, can anyone have best practice of this case ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var newData = data.map(function(obj) {
  return {
    text: obj.model_name,
    value: obj.vehicle_id,
  };
});
```

---

The problem with your code is that it is not doing anything. While `$.each` will iterate over the array, your function doesn't mutate the elements. It doesn't even create a new object, you are simply creating a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) with two [labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). You can think about it as being equivalent to

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i].model_name;
  arr[i].vehicle_id;
}
```

i.e. you are only referencing the properties, but are not doing anything with those values.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `map()`:

```
var newData = data.map(function(item) {
    return {
         text: item.model_name,
         value: item.vehicle_id
    };
});
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Answer (score 0):

Use 'map' instead of  'each'. 
Or use '$.each' like this:

```
var newdata = [];
$.each(data, function(index, Obj){
   newdata.push({
       text: Obj.model_name,
       value: Obj.vehicle_id
   })
});
```